# Learning Haskell: list comprehensions in C#

Tags: c#, linq, haskell

The following code is in Haskell. How would I write similar function in C#?

```
squareArea xs = [pi * r^2 | r <- xs]
```

Just to clarify... above code is a function, that takes as input a list containing radius of circles. The expression calculates area of each of the circle in the input list.

I know that in C#, I can achieve same result, by looping thru a list and calculate area of each circle in the list and return a list containing area of circles. My question is... Can the above code be written in similar fashion in C#, perhaps using lambda expressions or LINQ?

Comment: Wait, you have a function that starts with a capital?  That is illegal?

Comment: Why do you calculate the area with 2*pi*r? Isn't pi*r^2 or pi*r**2 the way to go?

Comment: `2*pi*r` will calculate the circumference of a circle, not its area.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<double> SquareArea(IEnumerable<int> xs)
{
    return from r in xs select Math.PI * r * r;
}
```

or

```
IEnumerable<double> SquareArea(IEnumerable<int> xs)
{
    return xs.Select(r => Math.PI * r * r);
}
```

which is very close to Haskell's

```
squareArea xs = map (\r -> pi * r * r) xs
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to not use Lambda expressions?
`squareArea xs = map (2*pi*) xs`

Comment: Sure. You can even shorten it `squareArea = map (2*pi*)` But that's not very close to C# any more.

Answer (score 6):

```
xs.Select(r => 2 * Math.PI * r * r)
```

is the right-hand side, I think (writing code in my browser, not compiled).

In general a Haskell list comprehension of the form

```
[e | x1 <- x1s, x2 <- x2s, p]
```

is probably something like

```
x1s.SelectMany(x1 =>
x2s.SelectMany(x2 =>
if p then return Enumerable.Singleton(e) else return Enumerable.Empty))
```

or

```
from x1 in x1s
from x2 in x2s
where p
select e
```

or something.  Darn, I don't have time to fix it up now, someone else please do (marked Community Wiki).

Answer (score 4):

dtb probably has the best version so far, but if you took it a bit further and put the methods in a static class and added the this operator like the following you could call the methods as if they were a part of your list:

```
public static class MyMathFunctions
{
    IEnumerable<double> SquareArea(this IEnumerable<int> xs)
    {
        return from r in xs select 2 * Math.PI * r * r;
    }

    IEnumerable<double> SquareAreaWithLambda(this IEnumerable<int> xs)
    {
        return xs.Select(r => 2 * Math.PI * r * r);
    }

}
```

Which could then be executed like this:

```
var myList = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5 };

var mySquareArea = myList.SquareArea();
```

Comment: Are both your SquareArea methods the same?  My eye's can't spot the difference:(

Comment: Yes, I meant to include the:

from r in xs select 2 * Math.PI * r * r;

in the first method, I've edited my post to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Func<IEnumerable<Double>, IEnumerable<Double>> 
   squareArea =  xs => xs.Select(r => Math.PI*r*r);
```